# Allowing extending classes only for specific classes - c#

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Is it possible to allow only specific classes to extend the class?

Suppose I have created class A but I want to allow to inherit this class only for class B and class C.
means class A should not allow extending for class.

is it possible to implement in that way in c#? using reflection or any other way?

Comment: By "extending" you mean inheriting?

Comment: yes, inheriting

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this by defining the other classes in the different assembly and declare the constructor of the base class as `internal`.

Answer (score 1):

One could check `this.GetType()` in the constructor of the base type (remember: `GetType()` returns the *concrete type*) and throw if it’s not an “approved type”.. however, such is a *run-time check* outside of the type-system.

```
protected BaseTypeCtor() {
  if (GetType() != typeof(OnlyAllowedSubtype))
    throw new Exception("Nope! Not allowed to subclass this type!");
}
```

Visibility restrictions — that which can cause *compile-time errors* — can generally only be controlled at the assembly level or for *all* subtypes.

If the types as indeed in different assemblies, marking the base constructor `internal` may be sufficient and is often cleaner. Unfortunately, C# currently cannot specify “internal *and* protected” as a modifier.

Comment: Unless one would want to create an analizer for this - that would work at compile time

Comment: Care to add an answer? I’ve never implemented a custom analyzer — so such did not cross my mind — and yet, with Roslyn (and associated “blurring” of ‘C#’ execution), that’s probably some good information to raise.

Comment: I'll take a look at the docs. I haven't implemented a custom analyzer either, I just know it can be done :)

Comment: Done,  if you want to take a look :) Getting the tooling and sample running was a bit harder than expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this at compile time, but don't want to use the `internal` modifier (for example, if this is in a package), what you can do is to [create your own Roslyn analyzer.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019)

Here's a very basic example of how you could achieve this for compile-time errors:

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class PreventInheritanceAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    public const string DiagnosticId = "PreventInheritanceAnalyzer";

    private static readonly string Title = "Title";
    private static readonly string MessageFormat = "Message format";
    private static readonly string Description = "Description";
    private const string Category = "Naming";
    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category,
        DiagnosticSeverity.Error, isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);
    private static HashSet<string> _acceptedClasses;

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics => ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);

    public PreventInheritanceAnalyzer()
    {
        _acceptedClasses = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "MyNumberOneClass", "MyOtherSpecialClass" });
    }

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
        context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.Analyze | GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.ReportDiagnostics);
        context.RegisterSymbolAction(AnalyzeSymbol, SymbolKind.NamedType);
    }

    private static void AnalyzeSymbol(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var namedTypeSymbol = (INamedTypeSymbol)context.Symbol;

        // if it's not a class, we are not interested
        if (namedTypeSymbol.TypeKind != TypeKind.Class)
        {
            return;
        }

        // if it doesn't inherit from our special class, we are not interested,
        // and if it does but its name is one we allow, we are still not interested
        if (namedTypeSymbol.BaseType == null || namedTypeSymbol.BaseType.Name != "MySpecialClass" || _acceptedClasses.Contains(namedTypeSymbol.Name))
        {
            return;
        }

        // otherwise, this is a bad class, report the error
        var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, namedTypeSymbol.Locations[0], namedTypeSymbol.Name);
        context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
    }
}
```

And this is a very basic unit test, to demonstrate that the above works:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
    var test = @"
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using System.Diagnostics;

        namespace ConsoleApplication1
        {
            public class MySpecialClass { }
            public class MyNumberOneClass : MySpecialClass { }
            public class MySuperSpecialClass : MySpecialClass { }
        }";

    VerifyCSharpDiagnostic(test, new[]
    {
        new DiagnosticResult
        {
            Id = "PreventInheritanceAnalyzer",
            Locations = new[] { new DiagnosticResultLocation("Test0.cs", 13, 18) },
            Message = "Message format",
            Severity = DiagnosticSeverity.Error
        }
    });
}
```